# How to analyze a nonlinear time series dataset?

Tags: chaos, time-series

I have a time series that appears chaotic that I would like to analyze with Python. To draw its logistic map, I must use the logistic equation: $$x_{t+1}=rx_{t}(1-x_{t})$$

I have the data in a text file but I can't find a way to estimate the growth rate r. Is there a way to achieve this? I feel like I don't fully understand this point...

And if this is not possible, it is therefore not possible to draw this map, so what other means can I use to ensure the chaotic behavior of my time series? Lyapunov exponents, Hénon map, determining of embedding’s time-delay?

Comment: The logistic map dynamics are sensitive to the value of r. For Python implementation, you could play around with libraries like numpy, scipy, matplotlib, and nolds (for Lyapunov exponents, for example)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map.